# Trying to fill in data if Null to take the previous that has data

Tags: ms-access-2007

Newbie here and probably to this process. I'm trying to fill in data that is Null on the ticker field to take the previous known data. See my example below. I don't know if I should write in a query or something else on MS Access 2007.

[image]

So for example under 0897250D CH Equity is null or blank. I want to take the data before it and fill it in.

Comment: I know its fairly new. Just want to bump this and see if anyone can help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Got my answer. I pretty much used the following....

```
Sub nullparts()
Dim i As String

Set myDb = CurrentDb()
Set MyRs = myDb.OpenRecordset("BB - HistoricalDividends")
MyRs.MoveFirst
Do While Not MyRs.EOF
MyRs.Edit
For Each myfld In MyRs.Fields
If myfld.Name = "Field1" Then
If MyRs(myfld.Name).Value <> "" Then
i = MyRs(myfld.Name).Value
Else
MyRs(myfld.Name).Value = i
MyRs.Update
End If
End If

Next myfld

MyRs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Now I'm trying to accomplish 2 more things.

1) Create an Import From Excel button on the database
2) Once imported, remove all lines that have no data on F2 to be deleted.